# Find $n\bmod 8$ when $n\bmod 56=29$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

A number when divided by $56$ gives the remainder $29$. If it is divided by $8$ then what will be the remainder?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm studying to improve my math.

Answer (score 7):

Since the remainder is $29$ when divided by $56$, the number in question can be expressed in form $$56k+29$$
for some integer $k$.
What is the remainder when $56k+29$ is divided by $8$ ?

Comment: This is indeed the answer @Hemanta Paul, we don't know two things. (i) we don't know quotient, (ii) we don't know the original number. We express the quotient by $k$. The first part of your question can mathematically be expressed as $56k+29$. Then because of the second part, you can find the final number, which will be $5$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 5, just check by using 29 mod 8=5, (56+29)mod 8 =5.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to notice is that $56$ is a multiple of $8$, so $56 \equiv 0 \pmod 8$. And $3 \times 8 = 24$, $29 - 24 = 5$, meaning that if $n \equiv 29 \pmod{56}$, then $n \equiv 5 \pmod 8$.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align}{\bf Hint}\quad n\ {\rm mod}\ 8k\, =&\,\ a\\ \Rightarrow\,n\, \equiv&\,\   a\!\!\! \pmod{8k}\\ \Rightarrow\, n\,\equiv&\,\ a\!\!\! \pmod 8\\ \Rightarrow\ n\ {\rm mod}\ 8 \ = &\,\ a\ {\rm mod}\ 8
\end{align}$

**Remark** $\ $ It is often the case that proofs involving the binary operator mod are simpler by first converting to an equivalent congruence (mod as a ternary relation), then proving it in congruence form, then, finally, converting back to operator form.